# how to use 'map' function to remove the last character from a line and then splits it at the commas

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def map(fn, seq):
    res = []

    for ele in seq:
        res.append(fn(ele))
    return res
```

Task: By using the above `map` function, write a `read_route_data` function that removes the last character from a line, (`'/n'`), and then splits the line at the commas. The result of `read_route_data` should be a `list` of tuples, with each `tuple` containing 4 datas:

For example: a list of the first 3 tuples should look like this:

```
>>> bus_stations = read_route_data(’smrt_routes.txt’)
>>> bus_stations[:3]:
[(’106’, ’1’, ’1’, ’43009’), (’106’, ’1’, ’2’, ’43179’), (’106’, ’1’, ’3’, ’43189’)]
```

This is my code:

```
def read_route_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = list(f)
  return map(lambda x: x.split(), lines)
```

Am I on the right track? I didn't manage to get a `list` of `tuple` but instead my output is:

```
[['106,1,1,43009'], ['106,1,2,43179'], ['106,1,3,43189']]
```

Comment: Hint: tuple function can convert a list to tuple.  tuple(['a', ' b', ' c']) will return ('a', ' b', ' c').

Comment: hint: `split` with no arguments splits on whitespace. If you want to split on commas, you'll need to do more...

Comment: please don't name that function as map, as map is the name of built-in.

Comment: To add to what @sjcipher said, if you do this in Python3 it is even more confusing, as it differs from the default `map` implementation.

Comment: I think overshadowing `map` is intentional. The instructor is effectively showing equivalent source code for map so the student understands what it's doing.

Comment: @Kevin I think so too, but as mentioned, it's not "equivalent source code" unless you are using Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: If you have to use map, you should probably split up your function so it isn't so all-encompassing. For instance, I might rewrite my original answer (which I will leave below) like so:

```
def read_route_data(line):    # take a line, not the whole file
    return tuple(line.rstrip('\n').split(','))
```

Now instead of doing the whole project in one function, we have a utility function that returns a properly formatted tuple by taking one of the lines from the file as input.

Now we can `map` over `f.readlines()` like so:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# later...
result = map(read_route_data, lines)
```

---

It looks like you want to do something like this:

```
def read_route_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()    # this is clearer than re-inventing the wheel
    return [tuple(line.rstrip('\n').split(',')) for line in lines]
```

Notice some things I did here:

- Used `f.readlines()` instead of `list(f)`. While this does the same thing, using the built-in way to do this is clearer since that is what most Python programmers would expect.
- In the list comprehension:

  - `line.split(',')` Split the line on the comma character
  - `tuple(line.split(','))` but make that a tuple instead of a list
  - `for line.rstrip('\n')` operate over lines with `\n` chopped off the right side

Comment: Yes, but we have to use the map function given to us...we can't use for loop.

Comment: `map` implements an operation from functional programming. It takes a sequence and applies a function to every element of the sequence, then returns the sequence with the new values. What are your arguments to map supposed to be? What is the function and what is the sequence? I added an example implementation to my answer.

Comment: `for line.rstrip('\n') in lines` isn't valid Python.

Comment: @DSM Yep, sorry. Fixed that in the first one but not in the second. :)